# entities not being persisted when saving them async

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactor, project-reactor, spring-async

I have the following code:

Controller:

```
eventNotifier.saveMessage(buildMessage(message, room, sender));
```

EventNotifier:

```
public void saveMessage(Message message){
        r.notify(EventConsumer.NEW_MESSAGE, Event.wrap(message));
    }
```

EventConsumer:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void onStartUp() {
        r.on(Selectors.R(MESSAGE_SAVED), createEventAndPush());
        r.on(Selectors.R(NEW_MESSAGE), saveMessage());
        r.on(Selectors.R(EVENT), pushToMixpanel());
    }
public Consumer<Event<Message>> saveMessage(){
        System.err.println("Calling save async");
        return event -> messageRepo.save(event.getData());
    }
```

turns out that the method `saveMessage` is never being called. I saw it being called once, during the startup server process.

I'm not sure this is reactor-related or spring related.

edit: I moved the saving process to a service, nothing changed

edit2: I logged the service action to see what is going on:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MessageService {

    @Autowired MessageRepository messageRepo;

    @Transactional
    public void save(Message m){
        try{
            log.info("Saving...");
            messageRepo.save(m);
            log.info("Saved");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

the output in console is:

```
2016-09-09 16:24:42.152  INFO 45041 --- [      wa-chub-2] com.inkdrop.app.services.MessageService  : Saving...
2016-09-09 16:24:42.154  INFO 45041 --- [      wa-chub-2] com.inkdrop.app.services.MessageService  : Saved
```

no logs from JPA, nothing!

Comment: If the `EventConsumer` is a spring bean, it explains `onStartup()` method being called only once when the bean is created.

Comment: yes, the `EventConsumer` is a spring bean

Answer (score 2):

Method annotated with `@PostConstruct` will only be called once by the spring context during bean creation. The `onStartup()` method explictly calls the `saveMessage()` method hence the you see the call once.

To save it each time you have to call it explicitly, its not going to be done magically.

Comment: I guess I'm not being clear enough. Each time I get a message, I explicity call the producer: `eventNotifier.saveMessage`. then, I can see in the logs the messages I put around the `save` in the `MessageService`, but no JPA logs.

Comment: Could you share complete consumer code? Or atleast its complete structure with empty methods?

Comment: yes: https://github.com/inkdrop/chathub-backend/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/inkdrop/app/consumers/EventConsumer.java

Comment: With out the reactor stuff the `MessageRepository .save()` method saves your entity? This looks to me related to spring data configuration thing.

Answer (score 1):

I will quote [`@PostContruct` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html):

> The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed after dependency injection is done to perform any initialization.

So it will be executed only once after your bean is initialized.

Comment: hmm, but I don't get it? I have other methods in the `EventConsumer`, like push the message to firebase, log it, etc. and they are being called whenever I want with no problem